# JS: Obtener suma total de la longitud de una propiedad en un JSON array en una sola instrucción

Tags: javascript, array, json

Lo que necesito es sumar en una sola instrucción todas las longitudes de un array el cual es una propiedad que se encuentra en todos los JSON de un JSON array.

Pongamos como ejemplo el siguiente json:

```javascript
[
    {
      id: 1,
      element: [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      element: [5]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      element: []
    }
]
```

La instrucción debería sumar `[1, 2, 3].length + [5].length + [].length` que debería dar 4. El problema es que necesito hacerlo en una sola instrucción, pero no he podido hacerlo, lo intenté con reduce pero no me queda claro cómo funciona.

```js
const array = [
    {
      id: 1,
      element: [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      element: [5]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      element: []
    }
];

console.log(array.reduce((accumulator, current, idx) => accumulator + array[idx].element.length));

console.log(array.reduce((accumulator, current) => accumulator + current.element.length));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta sería la solución con `reducer`, como segundo parámetro debes agregarle en que valor quieres que inicie el `reducer`.

```js
const array = [
    {
      id: 1,
      element: [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      element: [5]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      element: []
    }
];

console.log(array.reduce((accumulator, current) => accumulator + current.element.length, 0));
```